# Can a X-ray photon increase its frequency after scattering of a nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, collision, scattering, frequency

Can a X-ray photon increase its frequency after scattering of a nucleus? Let say nucleons are oscilating inside a nucleus due to interaction between residual SNF and Coloumb force... Can this oscillation be high enough to be compared with a X-ray photon oscillation and if the two oscillations are in phase the photon gains energy?

Answer (score 0):

Photons are elementary point particles , they do not oscillate, they have energy equal to $hν$ where $ν$ is the frequency of the electromagnetic wave a large number of same energy photons build up, in a complicated quantum field theory manner.The wave function of a photon describes the probability of measuring the photon at (x,y,z,t), it is the probability that has a wave structure. See [this experiment one photon at a time](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) building up an interference pattern.

> . Can this oscillation be high enough to be compared with a X-ray photon oscillation and if the two oscillations are in phase the photon gains energy?

This is a false way of looking at bound nuclear states, it is the energy levels and the incoming photon energy that play a role in X-ray photon+nucleus scattering. The energy levels in a nucleus are of order of MeV, and energy has to be conserved. An incoming X-ray photon of MeV energy  could excite a nucleon to a [higher energy level in a nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model), but energy has to be conserved.  A lower energy photon may leave the interaction region, but not a higher energy one.